# GitLab マージリクエストのターゲットブランチについて

Tags: gitlab

GitLabでマージリクエストのテストをしているのですが、
ターゲットブランチが「master」しか表示されません・・・。
マージリクエストは保護ブランチしかターゲットに出来ないのでしょうか？？
ご教授よろしくおねがいします。

バージョン：GitLab Community Edition 10.8.4

**ブランチの状態**
master(保護ブランチ)
　∟ develop
　　　∟ feature

**やりたいこと**
featureをdevelopへマージリクエストする。

**現状**
[image: マージリクエスト作成画面]
となってしまい、master以外選択できない状態です。
「develop」と打ってみても反応ありません。

**補足(経緯)**
少ない知識の中ブランチ戦略の提案書を作っています。
([参考サイト](https://havelog.ayumusato.com/develop/git/e513-git_branch_model.html#e513-2-1)を見ながら考えています。)
各ブランチへのマージ作業をクライアントツールではなくGitLab上でやったほうがいいのかと思って、このような質問をしました。

**追記**
･developブランチを保護ブランチにしてみましたが、結果変わらずでした。
･「No matching result」選択後、「master」すら選択できなくなりました。
(ページ更新したら選択できるようになります)
※もしやバグなんでしょうか・・・？

Comment: "master"ブランチ「以外」にマージリクエストを送りたい（けど出来ない）ということでしょうか？仮の名前でも構わないので、ブランチ同士の関係をもう少し詳しく書いておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。また、念のため確認ですが、ローカルで変更した変更はリモートにpush済みですか？

Comment: すみません！説明不足過ぎました・・・。ブランチ同士の関係を書いてみましたが不慣れで情報が足りなかったら指摘おねがいします。。。ローカルで変更下内容はリモートにpush済みです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました！
[GitLab Issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/42894)のやり取りをみていたら、英語(English)だと動くという内容をみてProfile SettingのPreferred languageを「日本語」から「English」に変更すると対象のブランチが表示されました！！